# How to find if a specific column of a pyspark dataframe contains numeric value

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark for my data transformation. Below is the dataframe which contains some alpha numeric characters.

```
    +------------------------------------------------+
    |Part1                                           |
    +------------------------------------------------+
    |1 HKY TBT TPP 190326 115346       5 C           |
    |51 HKK ABB TYR B    190326 000526    13 C       |
    +------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to extract the 2nd and 3rd integer values from the column. Below is my required dataframe

```
    +------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
    |Part1                                           |     Part2   |   Part3     |
    +------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
    |1 HKY TBT TPP 190326 115346       5 C           | 190326      |  115346     |
    |51 HKK ABB TYR B    190327 000526    13 C       | 190327      |  000526     |
    +------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I used substring but the position of the numeric values may change. Can you please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract`

```
df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    Row(Part1 = "1 HKY TBT TPP 190326 115346       5 C"),
    Row(Part1 = "51 HKK ABB TYR B    190326 000526    13 C")
])

regex = r'^(\d+)\s[^\d]*(\d+)\s[^\d]*(\d+)'
df.withColumn("Part2", regexp_extract(col("Part1"), regex, 2))\
    .withColumn("Part3", regexp_extract(col("Part1"), regex, 3))\
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+------+------+
|               Part1| Part2| Part3|
+--------------------+------+------+
|1 HKY TBT TPP 190...|190326|115346|
|51 HKK ABB TYR B ...|190326|000526|
+--------------------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! but if any of the character contains numeric value then not getting the required output. For example if you run the regex on the below DF you will get to know. I believe the regex needs to be modified a bit ::                                                                                           df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(Part1 = "1 HKY'9001 TBT TPP 190326 115346       5 C"),
    Row(Part1 = "51 HKK ABB'200D TYR'0000 B    190326 000526    13 C")
])   here still i need the previous output under Part2 and Part3 cols